# Passing current page url to control with Twig in Symfony

Tags: symfony, twig

Hi I have a modal contact form on my site that is available on each page of my site. When I render the contact controller on each page I was trying to use this

```
{% render controller('CorporateSiteBundle:Forms:contactUs', { 'contactOpen': contactOpen is defined, route: app.request.requestUri}) %}
```

Then on my controller page from all my contact form I wanted to grab that 'route' value that I was sending over. This is what I used:

```
$request->query->get('route');
```

But the form just seems to fail when it submits. Can anyone help with where I'm going wrong? Thanks

Comment: anyone got any ideas? Really struggling with this...

Answer (score 0):

you should try with

```
$request->get('contactOpen');
```

Comment: That didn't seem to do it, I'm also trying to get the 'route' variable. But it's saying it is null. I may be passing the app.request.requestUri variable wrong. I also tried 'route': app.request.requestUri (with single quotes).